# Conjugacy classes of $PSL_2(11)$ and $PGL_2(11)$ in $Aut(HN)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, sporadic-groups

How many conjugacy classes each of $PSL_2(11)$ and $PGL_2(11)$ subgroups are contained in the automorphism group of the Harada-Norton group?

Answer (score 4):

Two of ${\rm PSL}(2,11)$ (of lengths 103420800000 and 413683200000);

and two of  ${\rm PGL}(2,11)$ (of lengths 206841600000 and 413683200000).

Comment: Was that information already available online somewhere?

Comment: No, it was a computer calculation.